# Why isn't '=SUM('18-4:19-3'!I11)' summing cell I11 of worksheets labelled 18-4 to 19-3?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The formula is avouched [here](https://exceloffthegrid.com/how-to-sum-the-same-cell-across-multiple-worksheets/):

> *=SUM(‘FirstSheet:LastSheet’!A1)*
>
> Replace *FirstSheet* and *LastSheet* with the names of the worksheets you wish to sum between. In this example, *A1* would be the cell reference to sum.

Please see this question's title. I'm abbreviating 18-4 to April 2018, and 19-3 March 2019.

[image]

When I input `=SUM('18-4:19-3'!I11)`, the result is the same input, but no number!

Comment: I'm sure that you are getting an #Ref error. The Reason is the pattern of the Sheet Name you are using,, `=SUM(18-4:19-4!I11)` ,,, check the `4:19` these creates Row reference and the Formula gets confused !!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the example you provide. Kindly provide more detail. What result are you getting?

Comment: I tested as well and it works perfectly on my system.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Oops! I updated my post.

Comment: @ForwardEd Oops! I updated my post.

Comment: You probably are either entering it into a cell formatted as text or you have chosen to show formulas

Comment: @RonRosenfeld "You probably are either entering it into a cell formatted as text" You were right! Thanks. Problem solved. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you show is valid.

You probably are either entering that formula into a cell formatted as text or you have chosen to show formulas either by selecting that option, or by the keystroke shortcut.

Answer (score -2):

Basic reason behind the issue is, the Sheet name pattern, this is the Formula OP is using `=SUM(18-4:19-4!I11)` and while executing it Excel considers `4:19` (which is part of Sheet Name) as Row reference and pops up `File Name selection dialogue` and when OP selects the Workbook Name and finishes with `Ok`, Excel shows `Sheet Name Dialogue` and finally unable to find Sheets `18-4` and `19-4` and returns #Ref error and the formula looks like,`=SUM(18-4:19-'4'!I11)`.

[image]

## Edited:

Now to avoid the problem, Rename Sheets and it may be `18APR` and `19APR` and the Formula should `=SUM(18APR:19APR!A1)` or even `=SUM('18APR:19APR'!A1)`.

[image]

Comment: You are not using the same formula syntax as the OP has in his question.  Hence your results.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks. I agree with the comment above. So what's the correct formula?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal,,, it's simple the Correct Formula must avoid this Name pattern and it should like 18APR and 19APR and it should `=SUM(18APR:19APR!I11)` ☺

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,, this is the Formula OP has used `=SUM(18-4:19-4!I11)` and this appears after the error `=SUM(18-4:19-'4'!I11)` and this I've mentioned in my answer too!!